# Creating a variable to represent the maximum of range of value by unique in R

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have a data frame call df_jan. is this data frame I have the following Variable and Observation in each snapshot month.

```
Loan_ID           Jan_status     Feb_status  Mar_status 
000011                 1             3          2  
000122                 1             1          3  
090909                 3             4          5
780098                 2             1          5
001102                 3             1          1
```

I want to observe the highest status in each account for each months(observation) and then use those value in the new Max_status column:

```
Loan_ID           Jan_status     Feb_status  Mar_status  Max_status
000011                 1             3          2          3
000122                 1             1          3          3
090909                 3             4          5          5
780098                 2             1          5          5
001102                 3             1          1          3
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Use max(dataframe [  , 1:3])

Comment: You can try `df$Max_status <- df[, -1][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df[, -1]))]`.

Comment: Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing

Comment: `df %>%
  mutate(Max_status = pmax(Jan_status, Feb_status, Mar_status))` using `tidyverse`